# can't print variable from previous function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have got a database program to keep data in, and I can't solve this problem:

I have got two functions. When you input A into the program
the function called addy() starts
and ask for more input into a variable
then it returns to the main screen,
then the user can Input S
which starts Show()
and then it's supposed to show what you have added into the variable

PROBLEM:
It's not getting the value from the previous definition.

CODE:

```
def addy():
    os.system('cls')
    addel = input('what is the name of the operating system?: \n')
    os.system('cls')
    time.sleep(1)
    print(addel + ' Has been added to the database!')
    time.sleep(2)

    program()


def show():
    
    print('Heres a list of the operating systems you have added:')
    time.sleep(5)
    program()
    addel = addy()
    print(addel)  # this should print the value from the previous function
```

Comment: What is `program()`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is because you are not returning anything in the `addy()` function. Do you get `None`?

Comment: Oh, I actually managed to find a duplicate for this extremely common question that is phrased slightly differently every time. TODO: create a canonical version that is asked in the way that experienced programmers would ask, if they pretended not to know the answer.  Not sure it's a particularly *good* duplicate, but I hope it's sufficient for OP.

Comment: program() returns to the menu

Answer (score 0):

The are 2 reasons why

1. `Addel` is a local variable not a global one. Therefore, you can only use it in your `addy` function.
2. Say your intent was not to use it which is what it seems, you wrote

```
addel = addy()
```

the function `addy` has no return value so your code wont work.
to fix this write

```
return addel
```

as the last line in your addy function then it will work because now the function has a return value.

Comment: doesn't print :/